# I cannot add pictures to my document using latex and texstudio

Tags: graphics

It was working earlier but it does not work now.

```
\usepackage{verbatim,graphicx}
```

//Some code
    \includegraphics{dopler}

Both, image and  tex file are in the same folder.

```
         \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\setlength\textwidth{7in}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim,graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{2cm}

    \vspace{0.25cm}
    \begin{center}
    \small{\textit{For Partial Fulfillment of the Requirement for the
    \vspace{0.25cm}Award of the Degree 
\vspace{0.25cm}of}}  
\vspace{0.25cm}
\includegraphics[height=2.8cm]{man} %this line shows error: File `man' not found. \includegraphics[height=2.8cm]{man}
```

This was working earlier, then i installed some packages and it stopped working.
I tried reinstalling miktex but the issue still exists

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! A minimal (non)-working example would be nice.

Comment: What's the meaning of "not working"? Error or warnings? File name instead of image (option `draft`)? Image inclusion is driver dependend: Which kind of image, which TeX compiler is used?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\setlength\textwidth{7in}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim,graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{2cm}
 
 \vspace{0.25cm}
 \begin{center}
 \small{\textit{For Partial Fulfillment of the Requirement for the\\ \vspace{0.25cm}Award of the Degree\\ \vspace{0.25cm}of}} \\ \vspace{0.25cm}
\includegraphics[height=2.8cm]{man} %this line shows error: File `man' not found. \includegraphics[height=2.8cm]{man}

Comment: It seems that the `man` file is not there anymore. Or did you change it to an unsupported format?

Comment: That is not an mwe. If i add end center/document: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\setlength\textwidth{7in}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim,graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{2cm}

\vspace{0.25cm}
\begin{center}
\small{\textit{For Partial Fulfillment of the Requirement for the
\vspace{0.25cm}Award of the Degree 
\vspace{0.25cm}of}}  
\vspace{0.25cm}
\includegraphics[height=2.8cm]{example-image}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}`. Everythink works fine. Check your image path.